# How to avoid a shuffle on spark if the data is already on the correct executor

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have a spark job which reads from kafka.
There is one executor per kafka partition.
On the topic there is session information, the data is put onto the topic partitioned by sessionId already.

In spark we want to do a groupByKey operation using sessionId. As a developer I know that different messages for the same session will always be on a single executor. 
So spark should not need to move data between executors to do the shuffle. 
Is there a way to make sure that spark does not move data between executors for this operation?
Or any advice on how I would handle this issue?

Comment: if u r so sure that same session id data is in the same executor, probably u want to try `dataframe.foreachpartition()` this mehod gives u an iterator and while u iterate there is no shuffle involved